# TypeScript: Creating a new object from a discriminated union without casting

Tags: typescript, object, casting, unions

[Link to TS playground of the following Q](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMicsACYBcyAzmFKAOYDcxpYWE1A5DtwDRsSMYBAA25GtSKlZyMAAsmARmp0GIFkLmKmAJmogArgFsARtFayAvoVuEEAexB1k5CPCNiweALwFtXU1VZG4FCHQBQKVNA2RlPQBmO0JCUEhYRBQMbAAhANkKNXomK3ZOHlyo2RFxSWltWSDGROozR0cxCDgQMrl5GMYAFkNTCyg+5Ft7JxcwNw84LzB8-xl2Qdb5KCMIQSbBkeQhgFYANhSHZ1d3T28AMVEJGmQ17RxqW6XvHH3SXM+i2WuUE9g42GQOBA6ByKH8sLwAB80JxcqlZq4EFBupAAHIQADuqEGr2QAApwVwUdgcABtbiU7gAXWQyNhuXpjKZAEpqFCYZxXgA+AqkbFgIxQECi-pFUIgQlkcjVfryTh-fq1Z6Au5gR51Gi0ylMjVTFJAA)

Suppose I have the following type and variable declarations:

```js
interface TypeA {
    id: string;
    type: 'A',
    fields: {
        thing1: string;
        thing2: number;
    }
}

const defaultA = {
    thing1: 'hey',
    thing2: 123
}

interface TypeB {
    id: string;
    type: 'B',
    fields: {
        thing3: boolean;
        thing4: number;
    }
}

const defaultB = {
    thing3: true,
    thing4: 456
}

const defaultFields = {
    A: defaultA,
    B: defaultB,
}

type AnyType = TypeA | TypeB
```

Trying to create a new `AnyType` via:

```js
const createNewThing = (type: TypeA['type'] | TypeB['type']): AnyType => {
    return {
        id: 'new id',
        type,
        fields: defaultFields[type],
    }
}
```

throws a TS error:

```
Type '{ id: string; type: "A" | "B"; fields: { thing1: string; thing2: number; } | { thing3: boolean; thing4: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'AnyType'.
  Type '{ id: string; type: "A" | "B"; fields: { thing1: string; thing2: number; } | { thing3: boolean; thing4: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'TypeB'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"A" | "B"' is not assignable to type '"B"'.
        Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"B"'.(2322)
```

To get around this, I can cast the object being created as `AnyType`:

```js
const createNewThing = (type: TypeA['type'] | TypeB['type']): AnyType => {
    return {
        id: 'new id',
        type,
        fields: defaultFields[type],
    } as AnyType;
}
```

But I'd rather avoid casting if possible. Is there some way to get around this other than through casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a limitation of typescript: discriminated unions only apply to top level fields.

In your posted example, `thing1 thing2 thing3 thing4` are all nested under `fields`. If you moved them up a level, your example should work.

For more, see this [blog post](https://blog.asana.com/2020/01/typescript-quirks/).